# How to get a form in html sent to my email?

Tags: php, html, email

I need to have a form send an email to me with all of the information...
It is coded in HTML5 and I'm not sure how to get an email with all of the information ordered.

```
<article id="contact" class="panel">
                            <header>
                                <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                            </header>
                            <form action="email.php" method="post">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="6u">
                                            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="6u">
                                            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="12u">
                                            <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="12u">
                                            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="8"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="12u">
                                            <input type="submit" value="Send Message" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
 </article>
```

My php is :

```
<?php
mail('myemail@gmail.com', $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message']);
```

?>

Your email has been sent.

Comment: Can you post your php as well please? It is difficult to see what's going wrong without all the code.

Comment: I have added it to the OP

Comment: You can't just add parameters to the `mail()` function as your form grows and expect it to magically send everything. You should start with the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php although a library like Swift or PHP Mailer will make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
    $to = $_POST["email"];
    $message = "
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
     <p>Name : ".$_POST["name"]."</p>
     <p>".$_POST["subject"]."</p>
     <p>".$_POST["message"]."</p>
    </body>
    </html>
    ";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: yourname <youremailadress>' . "\r\n";
    mail($to,$_POST["subject"],$message,$headers);
?>
```

The mail will be sent with html formated. It will display well on mail client suporting HTML (all modern ones).
Don't forget to secure your formular with a captcha to prevent e-mail bombing.
You can also add some code to check if all fields have been completed.

Hope it helps

Comment: How would I use my website in XAMPP

Comment: You should post another question and provide more details, like setup environment. By the way, did my answer helped ?